# Why SELECT and UPDATE Return Different Record Counts/Affected

Tags: sql, sql-update

I wrote a SELECT query to find out how many records will be impacted with my UPDATE query.

The SELECT and UPDATE returned different record counts.

Here is my SELECT query:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
JOIN T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.Name IS NULL
  AND T2.Status = 'happy'
```

Here is my UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.Name = T2.Name
FROM T1
JOIN T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.Name IS NULL
  AND T2.Status = 'happy'
```

My SELECT returns 19K records, and my UPDATE affects 12K records. Please note that the WHERE clause is exactly the same for both the SELECT and UPDATE.

What is causing the discrepancy in records counts between the SELECT and UPDATE queries?

Can you please help me understand what is happening here?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `UPDATE` will never update a row more than once.  `SELECT` however, will happily return the same (target) row many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can happen on a one to many join when you're updating the one side. In your case, it looks like there are more than one `T2` row for some of your `T1` rows, and the server will return the `T1` row as many times as there is matches in the `T2` table.

Check if this matches your update count:

```
SELECT count(distinct T1.ID)
FROM T1
JOIN T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.Name IS NULL
  AND T2.Status = 'happy'
```

Answer (score 4):

One possible reason: You have instances of `ID` where more than one `T2` record exists for the corresponding `T1` record

Answer (score 0):

Instead of select *, try distinct t1.name. Since you are updating name in T1 table, that might give you the exact number of rows being effected in update.

hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and after looking deeper into the data I found out that the IDs used in the JOIN criteria were not unique (had duplicates) in one of the tables. It looks like when doing SELECT it takes all matching, but when doing UPDATE it only takes the first one out of the duplicates.